# Introduction to morse theory with applications to optimization

Tags: reference-request, optimization, manifolds, nonlinear-optimization, morse-theory

I am wondering if there are any easy-to-read introduction materials on morse theory (especially with applications to nonconvex optimization) for people with non-math background.